# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error while accessing valid, non-released object

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access, autorelease, nszombie

I have a weird issue that comes up while releasing an object. In the object's `dealloc` method I am releasing another (sub) object. When this sub object is released I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I am pretty sure the sub-object is a valid pointer right before I call release on it.

This is how I've confirmed the weirdness - I set a break point inside the dealloc method, right before the release of the sub-object, and it is allocated! I can send it messages and it responds correctly. Another weird bug is that, if NSZombieEnabled is set to YES, I dont get an error at all, not even NSZombie's usual error that says I've sent a message to a deallocated object, the code runs properly.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

---

*** EDIT 1 ***

I've found out that if I place the [super dealloc] in the end of the dealloc, it crashes, but if I place it at start, it won't. I've had something similar before, only the other way - app crashed if I [super dealloc] in start of my dealloc, and didn't at the end.

Why does it make a difference and when should you use what?

---

*** EDIT 2 ***

Scratch Edit #1! It doesn't work either way.

Comment: Can you provide some code which describes your problem?

Comment: Please post some relevant code showing where it crashes and how to release that object. Also try using instruments for Zombie detection.

Comment: Unfortunatly its a pretty complicated code, which I'd like not to expose... that's why I'm asking for a general answer...

Comment: FWIW, if NSZombieEnabled is set, **no memory is freed at all**, so your code may seem to run properly, but in fact it leaks like a sieve. Use that setting for debugging purposes only.

Comment: Yeah I know, wasn't counting on releasing it with NSZombieEnabled to have it running, just thought I should mention it.

Comment: The release itself is simple:- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [fetchingQueue release];
}. Switching the order of the dealloc and the release makes no difference. Instruments also found no NSZombies while NSZombieEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your dealloc routine happen to look like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [super dealloc];
   [otherObject release];
}
```

if so, change the order. If you call `[super dealloc]`, your object gets vanished from memory, trying to acces otherObject later will cause you to access non-allocated memory -> EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: it doesn't matter, I get the same result for both situations.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how the object is initialized, will be hard for anyone to know for sure.

```
MyObject *someObject = [MyObject alloc] init...]; // Make sure you aren't autoreleasing here
// do some stuff with someObject

[someObject release];
```